# Concatenating two string variables in bash appending newline

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a variable `final_list` which is appended by a variable `url` in a loop as:

```
while read url; do
    final_list="$final_list"$'\n'"$url"
done < file.txt
```

To my surprise the `\n` is appended as an space, so the result is:

```
url1 url2 url3
```

while I wanted:

```
url1
url2
url3
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

New lines are very much there in the variable `"$final_list"`. `echo` it like this **with double quotes**:

```
echo "$final_list"
url1
url2
url3
```

OR better use `printf`:

```
printf "%s\n" "$final_list"
url1
url2
url3
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you explain a bit on what is happening.

Comment: Quoting is of utmost importance in Unix shells. Without quotes shell doesn't apply any expansion rules and treats new lines as space.

Comment: Without the quotes, any white space (including newlines) in the expansion of `$final_list` is treated as a word separator, not literal characters to print. `echo` receives only 3 arguments, the actual URLs. With quotes, `echo` receives a single argument, the string that contains urls and the newlines that separate them.

Answer (score 3):

It may depend on how you're trying to display the final result.  Try outputting the resulting variable within double-quotes:

```
echo "$final_list"
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding one more possible option if anyone like to try.

**With String Value :**

Command : `echo "This is the string I want to print in next line" | tr " " "\n"`

Output :

```
This
is
the
string
I
want
to
print
in
next
line
```

**With Vars used :**

```
finallist="url1 url2 url3"          
url="url4 url5"                     
echo "$finallist $url" | tr " " "\n"
```

Output :

```
url1
url2
url3
url4
url5
```

if you like to have few words to be in one line and few in next line, try with different separater. (like - or : or ; or etc...)