# Concatenate strings with newline in bash?

Tags: bash, newline, string-concatenation

I have seen [Concatenating two string variables in bash appending newline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18535902/concatenating-two-string-variables-in-bash-appending-newline) - but as i read it, the solution is:

> echo it like this **with double quotes**:

... but I cannot seem to reproduce it - here is an example:

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 5.0.17(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

$ mystr=""
$ mystr="${mystr}First line here\n"
$ mystr="${mystr}Second line here\n"
$ mystr="${mystr}Third line here\n"
$ echo $mystr
First line here\nSecond line here\nThird line here\n
```

So far, as expected - and here is the double quotes:

```
$ echo "$mystr"
First line here\nSecond line here\nThird line here\n
```

Again I do **not** get the new lines - so the advice "*echo it like this with double quotes*" seems *not* to be correct.

Can anyone say *accurately*, how do I get proper newlines output (not just `\n`) when concatenating strings in `bash`?

Comment: `mystr="${mystr}First line here\n"` but the code you linked does `"stuff"$'\n'"stuff"` not `"stuff\n"`.

Comment: Ah, thank you @KamilCuk - I did indeed misread the original post, that is why I ended up misunderstanding my own example! Thanks, that clarifies things ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add a newline, not two characters `\` and `n`, to the string.

```
mystr=""
mystr+="First line here"$'\n'
mystr+="Second line here"$'\n'
mystr+="Third line here"$'\n'
echo "$mystr"
```

*Or* you can interpret `\` escape sequences - with `sed`, with `echo -e` or with `printf "%b" "$mystr"`.

Comment: Thanks, accepting this answer, as it both identified the source of my confusion, and also includes the `-e` switch.

Answer (score 1):

You should do

```
nabil@LAPTOP:~$ echo -e $mystr
First line here
Second line here
Third line here

nabil@LAPTOP:~$
```

You can find the other options in the man

```
 -e     enable interpretation of backslash escapes
```

Comment: Thanks - this is correct, however, I've accepted the other answer, as it also revealed the source of my confusion with the post linked in the OP.